# Trying to understand ?. (null-conditional) operator in C#

Tags: c#, nullable, roslyn, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

I have this very simple example:

```
class Program
{
    class A
    {
        public bool B;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        System.Collections.ArrayList list = null;

        if (list?.Count > 0)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Contains elements");
        }

        A a = null;

        if (a?.B)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Is initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

The line `if (list?.Count > 0)` compiles perfectly which means that if `list` is `null`, the expression `Count > 0` becomes `false` by default.

However, the line `if (a?.B)` throws a compiler error saying I can't implicitly convert `bool?` to `bool`.

Why is one different from the other?

Comment: Which framework version is this ?

Comment: @Veverke it is not the .NET framework version that conrolls this, it is the compiler you use. `.?` was introduces in C# 6 which was included with Visual Studio 2015 and newer

Comment: See [What exactly does ‘lifted’ mean?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/06/27/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean/)

Comment: If you make the property "public bool? B" on class A, does it work?

Comment: @BrianMains no, it does not. See the accepted answer.

Comment: And note VB.NET took a different way here. I.e. both of these work as expected, though that does mean there's other interesting inconsistencies.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In your first case (`list?.Count`) the operator returns an `int?` - a nullable `int`.
The `>` operator is defined for nullable integers so that if the `int?` has no value (is null), the comparison will return `false`.

In your second example (`a?.B`) a `bool?` is returned (because if `a` is null, neither `true` nor `false` but `null` is returned). And `bool?` cannot be used in an `if` statement as the `if` statement requires a (non-nullable) `bool`.

You can change that statement to:

```
if (a?.B ?? false)
```

to make it work again. So the null-coalescing operator (`??`) returns `false` when the null-conditional operator (`?.`) returned `null`.

Or (as TheLethalCoder suggested):

```
if (a?.B == true)
```

Comment: Would `if (a?.B == true)` give the same effect?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder While C# limits `bool` values to `false` and `true`, the .NET Framework does not, and non-C# methods may give you what can be in pseudo-C# as `(bool) 2`. Such a value is true enough to enter an `if` block if used as the condition, but does not compare equal to `true`.

Comment: Whether `if (a?.B == true)` works or not, when I see it, I have the gut instinct to chime in "don't compare booleans to true (or false), use them directly," as would normally be appropriate when someone writes `if (someCondition == true)` instead of `if (someCondition)`.  I'm not sure what to make of a construction that ends up encouraging `(... == true)`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor it's not comparing a `bool` to `true`, but a `bool?`

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes, I understand that;  my point is that it's jarring to see a place where `== true` *is* the right thing.

Comment: Also will (b?.A == false) give a similar effect?

Comment: @KrishMunot what do you mean? there is no variable called `b` in the question.

Comment: @RenéVogt They obviously mistyped :-/ (a?.B == false) works as well. The issue here is null.

Answer (score 81):

- `list?.Count > 0`: Here you compare an `int?` to an `int`, yielding a `bool`, since [lifted comparison operators return a `bool`, not a `bool?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507497/87698).
- `a?.B`: Here, you have a `bool?`. `if`, however, requires a `bool`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that `list?.Count` basically becomes `int? tmp = list?.Count` and then of course `tmp > 0` evaluates to false.

This was the missing piece.

Comment: An important point is "if, however, requires a bool". This is why one can express `a?.B == true` and it should compile. As obvious as that is, it can elude someone looking too closely at syntax.