# When using a null conditional operator in a conditional statement, how is the null case handled?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have the following code here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   StringBuilder[] s = new StringBuilder[3];
   if (s[0]?.Length > 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("hi");
   }
}
```

My understanding is that the expression that goes inside the if statement, must be a boolean expression. A boolean expression (my understanding I could be wrong) is an expression that evaluates to true or false.

In this case, the null-conditional operator will return null since, the default value of an element within an array of reference-type variables, is null. Therefore, this if statement is equivalent to

```
bool? x = null;
if (x)
{ 
   // do cool things here */ 
}
```

But this gives me a syntax error: cannot convert null to bool.

Therefore, how it is possible that the above example with StringBuilder works? My understanding that the better approach to the code above should be to combine it with null-coalescing operator, as in:

```
if (s[0]?.Length > 0 ?? false) {}
```

Thanks all :)

Comment: I hope you already answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

In your statement

```
if (x)
```

`x` not a *Boolean Expression* it's a *Nullable* `bool`. In short, you can't put statements that do not evaluate to a *Boolean expression* in an `if` statement.

However, you can `Lift` it by specifying `true` or `false`, this takes advantage of the *Nullable* `Lifted` operators. E.g

```
if (x == true)
//or
if (x == false)
```

Similarly, lifting is what's causing the following to work.

```
int? i = null;
if(i > 0) {...}
```

This can also be seen with the *Null-Conditional* operator

```
if (SomeObj?.Length > 0)
```

What's happening here is, the *Null-Conditional* is forcing `Length` (which is an `int`) to be interpreted as a *Nullable* `int` it gets checked for null and lifted to `int` for the comparison

***Note** : The actual generated IL when reinterpreted would look something like this*

```
if ((object)obj == null || obj.Length <= 0)
```

Even though the generated code is counter-intuitive, *lifting* is a special case for *Nullable-Types* and the compiler treats them differently for various conversion and operators

You can find out more by perusing the [Standard ECMA-334 5th Edition specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf) on *Lifted operators* and *Lift Conversions*

> **12.4.8 Lifted operators**
>
> Lifted operators permit predefined and user-defined operators that
> operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable
> forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined
> and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as
> described in the following

Comment: Sorry, but "`Length` (which is an `int`) gets interpreted as a _Nullable_ `int`" is not correct.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry i muddled up the comment, anyway i like your answer, upvote

Answer (score 1):

Your equivalence is wrong.

Writing `var x = s[0]?.Length > 0;` is the same as `bool x = false`, not `bool? x = null`;

The un-optimized IL produced is:

```
IL_0013:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0014:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0015:  ldelem.ref  
IL_0016:  dup         
IL_0017:  brtrue.s    IL_001D
IL_0019:  pop         
IL_001A:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_001B:  br.s        IL_0025
IL_001D:  call        System.Text.StringBuilder.get_Length
IL_0022:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0023:  cgt         
IL_0025:  stloc.1     // x
```

The line `brtrue.s` simply branches when `s[0]` is "`true`, not `null`, or non-zero" and thus jumps to the code that compares the `.Length` with `0` - otherwise it hits `br.s` branch which simply jumps to the code that sets the result to `false`.

Hence it is the equivalent of `bool x = false` and not `bool? x = null`

> My understanding is that the expression that goes inside the if statement, must be a boolean expression. A boolean expression (my understanding I could be wrong) is an expression that evaluates to true or false.

You are correct in your understanding.

The code de-compiles in ILSpy as:

```
StringBuilder[] array = new StringBuilder[3];
StringBuilder obj = array[0];
if (obj != null && obj.Length > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sigh, I believe a bit more Googling has afforded me an answer!
This question here helped me out: [Trying to understand ?. (null-conditional) operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103963/trying-to-understand-null-conditional-operator-in-c-sharp)

Basically, for certain operators (I believe <, >, <=, >=) these operators are 'lifted' to deal with the null case. If either of the operands in these binary operators are null, they automatically return false.

For example

```
int? x = 5;
int? y = 10;
bool b = x < y; // true
```

Why does this work? Because it's semantically equivalent to:

```
bool b = (x.HasValue && y.HasValue) ? (x.Value < y.Value) : false;
```

If one of the operands doesn't have a value, always return false.

Thanks SO!